# HTML email misalignment in Outlook 2013?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, vertical-alignment

I have a very simple HTML email template - just used for testing - and it has 5 columns with one word in, the problem is in Outlook 2013 the first column is always mis-aligned vertically. Here is the HTML.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>    
    <table width="95%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="wrapper_table" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="content_1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top;"><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="test" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top;"><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        Row
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        Row
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        Row
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        Row
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        Row
                                    </td>
                                </tr></table></td>
                    </tr></table></td>
        </tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

The result in Outlook 2013 is:

[image: Outlook 2013]

This is the code output from Outlook

```
<!DOCTYPE html><br />
<html><body>    <br />
    <table width="95%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="wrapper_table" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><br />
                <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="content_1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top;"><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><br />
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="test" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top;"><tr><td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;"><br />
                                        Row<br />
                                    </td><br />
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;"><br />
                                        Row<br />
                                    </td><br />
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;"><br />
                                        Row<br />
                                    </td><br />
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;"><br />
                                        Row<br />
                                    </td><br />
                                    <td style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;"><br />
                                        Row<br />
                                    </td><br />
                                </tr></table></td><br />
                    </tr></table></td><br />
        </tr></tbody></table></body></html><br />
```

The problem is related to all the extra BR tags that outlook adds, but what can I do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, external styles are not supported in emails, and styles must be applied inline per tag. Have you tried adding `valign="top"` on each of the nested tds?

```
<td valign="top">
    Row
</td>
```

You might also try closing up any whitespace that's nested within your tags, for example:

```
<td valign="top">Row</td>
```

Comment: As I said, the styles are inlined before the email is sent, I have a PHP function to do this, I'm not using external styles. I have tried valign and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tested your email without the function / by constructing it with the intended output? I don't think you should include that function here.

Comment: Yes I tried it without, I've also checked the source of the email in outlook and it contains all the styles etc as the code I have written, however is adds a lot of BR tags, but they are the same for each cell so all should be misaligned if that was the problem.

Comment: Can you include the outputted code post-php? That would be easier to work with than the separated code that's currently provided in your question (and I'm not talking about the extra stuff that Outlook might be appending). Just the HTML email code as you would construct it without php.

Comment: Let me retract my previous statement. I just did a test, if I add a BR tag before the first TD then it all aligns ok. I shall update my question

@stuart Kershaw - I have put in the code with inline styles now, as is sent to outlook

Comment: Are you certain Outlook is adding those line breaks? You've tested this in other email clients?

Comment: Also, your vertical-align is being added as a property style="vertical-align: top;" I suggested adding the attribute valign="top"

Comment: I could kiss you! I hadn't thought to check in another client and assumed it was outlook causing the problem. I have just ran some tests and have found that it is codeigniter's email class adding the extra tags.

Comment: So the problem seems to be me being stupid For some reason I was running the email body through - nl2br - before sending it. Fool I am!

Comment: Glad you found the issue! There are so many oddities to get caught up on with emails, it's always trial and error with these things.